# Python Caffe: ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found

Tags: python, compilation, installation, caffe

The original question is pasted in [Caffe-Users](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/caffe-users/sTlTmcmdAmU/HG-RA2u-AwAJ).

I compiled caffe by using the GCC4.8.2 successfully, and the `MINIST` examples can run correctly. But when I tried to use caffe in python, I met with the problem as follows:
[image]

I use Anaconda2 in my computer, and the version of GCC in OS is GCC4.4.6. In order to compile caffe with GCC4.8.2, I installed it in `/opt`. What's more, the output of `ldd _caffe.so` is as follow:

[image]

It seems the `_caffe.so` linked to `libc.so.6` of GCC4.8.2 correctly. What's more, the `cv2.so` compiled by GCC4.8.2 runs into the same problem. Any advice can be useful.

Comment: are you running the command inside the caffe folder?

Comment: No, I have appended the `$CAFFE_HOME/python` into `$PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: i don't remember how,but this definetly linked to a bad installation...did you build pycaffe? make pycaffe? did you run tests after? if so try installing glib and see sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev

Comment: did you build with CMAKE with this flag  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/g++-4.8?

Comment: I have did all the steps recommended in [BLVC Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#compilation), and the `make runtest` passed all test, None of them failed. There is no error in running the command tool `caffe`, the problem just occurs in python.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I use centOS 6.3, the GCC installed in system is GCC4.4.6. The Linux kernel is 2.6.32

Comment: could you redo make pycaffe ?since it is not specified by http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#compilation

Comment: I have run the command `make pycaffe` in the beginning, or there would not be the library `_caffe.so`. I think I have compiled the `pycaffe` successfully, the problem is why it links to `/lib64/libc.so` when executing, the `ldd` shows it have linked to `gcc-4.8.2/lib64/libc.so` successfully. I am not familiar with the mechanism of program execution.